# Tls protocols: is the simple diffie hellman key exchange still used these days?

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, key-exchange

Or did it mostly get replaced by ecdh for key exchange and rsa for authentication ?

Comment: What do you mean by "simple" in "the simple DH KE"? Finite-Field DH with RSA authentication or (denoted `DHE` in TLS notation) or the static Finite-Field / EC DH with the server having a static DH key that is contained in the certificate (denoted `DH` or `ECDH` in TLS notation)?

Comment: Like if its used at all these days on websites? if i check the tls protocols of websites for example this one it always says that edch is used for keyexchange and never the normal diffie hellman key exchange algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TLS, Diffie-Hellman (non-EC) can be used in `TLS_DH_*` ciphersuites ("static DH"), and in `TLS_DHE_*` ciphersuites ("ephemeral DH").

Static DH occurs when the server's certificate contains a public DH key. This never gained traction; historically, the US federal government promoted use of DH for key exchange because, at that time, RSA was still patented. However, nobody in practice does that anymore, except maybe in some old, hidden systems in some US federal organizations, and not for general public consumption.

Ephemeral DH is quite widely supported. For instance, my own Web server uses the default SSL configuration of Apache+mod_ssl on Ubuntu 16.04, and offers the following protocol versions and cipher suites:

```
  TLSv1.0:
     server selection: uses client preferences
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLSv1.1: idem
  TLSv1.2:
     server selection: uses client preferences
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

As you can see, there are quite a lot of `DHE` suites here. The server's certificate contains a public RSA key, so all the `DHE` suites are tagged `DHE_RSA`, which means: "the server sends DH parameters, signed with its RSA key".

Now, that the server *offers* `DHE` ciphersuites does not mean that they actually get used. As shown above, my server follows the client preferences, i.e. uses the first ciphersuite it knows of among the list sent by the client, during the initial TLS handshake. Thus, if the client supports `DHE` *and* `ECDHE` ciphersuites, but sends the `ECDHE` suites first, then the server will choose one of these `ECDHE` suites.

Moreover, modern Web browsers tend to drop `DHE` support. On my machine (a macOS Sierra laptop), I have three up-to-date browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Safari), and none of them offers `DHE` cipher suite support (all happily negotiate `ECDHE_RSA` if the server supports it, but fall back to plain `RSA` key exchange if the server does not support `ECDHE`). In that sense, `DHE` ciphersuites are an obsolescent feature. Take care that not all TLS is about Web browsers talking to Web servers; there are a lot of applications that also use TLS, and do not necessarily follow the browser trends. Moreover, modern Web browsers are automatically updated, so they are always "cutting edge", while servers and applications can lag for quite some time (many years even). Still, it can be expected that TLS libraries slowly deprecate `DHE` ciphersuites, or possibly drop support altogether, since `ECDHE` ciphersuites are more efficient (my own [TLS library](https://www.bearssl.org/), for instance, supports `ECDH` and `ECDHE` but never supported `DH` or `DHE`).

**Summary:** `DHE` ciphersuites still work on a number of existing servers, but don't see much usage in practice when clients are Web browsers, and support is expected to dwindle and disappear over time. As you say, indeed, `DHE` was replaced by `ECDHE`.